# net-snmp mib loading and snmptranslate

Tags: snmp, net-snmp, mib

I'm trying to run snmptranslate on my system but it does not work, even if I did everything by tutorial from net-snmp.org. They say it should work but it doesn't.

I have a debian 6 server and net-snmp 5.4.3. I tried what they say [here](http://www.net-snmp.org/wiki/index.php/TUT:Using_and_loading_MIBS), the official tutorial but it still returns same error:

```
No log handling enabled - turning on stderr logging
MIB search path: 
/home/las/.snmp/mibs:/usr/share/mibs/site:/usr/share/snmp/mibs:/usr/share/mibs/iana:/usr/share/mibs/ietf:/usr/share/$
Cannot find module (SNMPv2-TC): At line 10 in /usr/share/mibs/netsnmp/UCD-DLMOD-MIB
Cannot find module (SNMPv2-SMI): At line 34 in /usr/share/mibs/netsnmp/UCD-SNMP-MIB
Cannot find module (SNMPv2-TC): At line 37 in /usr/share/mibs/netsnmp/UCD-SNMP-MIB
Did not find 'enterprises' in module #-1 (/usr/share/mibs/netsnmp/UCD-SNMP-MIB)
Did not find 'DisplayString' in module #-1 (/usr/share/mibs/netsnmp/UCD-SNMP-MIB)
... and so on
```

I even created ~/.snmp/mibs directory and put there 2 cisco mibs but after I tried to run snmptranslate, I get the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution. I installed this package:

```
sudo apt-get install snmp-mibs-downloader
```

After installing, run this command:

```
download-mibs
```

It should download all necessary mibs.

Comment: It could be necessary to edit /etc/snmp/snmp.conf and comment the line  with word **mibs**.